# Menu dinamico Asp.net c# Opcion no aparece

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tengo el siguiente menu en una app MVC 5

en la vista _Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acerca de", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacto", "Contact", "Home")</li>

                @*Obtiene el menu a traves de Ajax*@
                <div id="MenuDinamico"></div>

            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
```

y su correspondiente script en el mismo archivo

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        getMenuUser(1);
    });

    function getMenuUser(UsuarioId) {
        var parametrosAjax = {
            "UsuarioId": UsuarioId
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetMenuUsuario", "Menu")',
            data: parametrosAjax,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: false,
            success: function (Data) {
                if (Data.length > 0) {
                    var MenuUsuario = ''
                    $.each(Data, function (idx, OpcMenu) {
                        MenuUsuario += OpcMenu;
                    })
                    $('#MenuDinamico').append(MenuUsuario);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
    }



</script>
```

en el controller tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
        private List<string> _GetMenuUsuario(int UsuarioId)
    {
        // para test
        List<OpcionMenu> lstMenuUsuario = new List<OpcionMenu>();

        OpcionMenu opcMenu = new OpcionMenu();
        opcMenu.Id = 1;
        opcMenu.Nombre = "Cierre Mes";
        opcMenu.RolId = 1;
        opcMenu.PadreId = 0;
        opcMenu.AreaId = 1;
        opcMenu.AreaName = "Kam";
        opcMenu.ActionName = "Inicio";
        opcMenu.ControllerName = "Cierre";
        opcMenu.Visible = true;
        opcMenu.Activo = true;
        lstMenuUsuario.Add(opcMenu);


        List<string> lstOpcionesMenu = new List<string>();
        foreach (var OpcionMenu in lstMenuUsuario)
        {

            string LineaMenu = "<li> @Html.ActionLink('";
            LineaMenu += OpcionMenu.Nombre.ToString().Trim();
            LineaMenu += "', '";
            LineaMenu += OpcionMenu.ActionName.ToString().Trim();
            LineaMenu += "', '";
            LineaMenu += OpcionMenu.ControllerName.ToString().Trim();
            LineaMenu += "', new { area = '";
            LineaMenu += OpcionMenu.AreaName.ToString().Trim();
            LineaMenu += "' }, null) </li>";

            lstOpcionesMenu.Add(LineaMenu);
        }



        return lstOpcionesMenu;
    }
```

el problema, es que no aparece la opcion en el menu a pesar que el actionLink esta correctamente escrito.

Me falta algo?

Agrego una imagen de como me aparece el resultado en la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos, y gracias por leer.

Comment: intenta hacer un debug, si realmente esta regresando el json con los datos.

Comment: Hola, si, el debug me muestra que genera la linea  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cierre Mes", "Inicio", "Cierre", new { area = "Kam" }, null)</li>  pero en la pagina aparece como si la hubiese escrito dentro en un div... Sabes como arreglar eso?.

Comment: agregue una imagen de como se ve el resultado

Comment: es porque lo estas agregando dentro del div. tienes que corregir la forma en que agregar tu menu en el controller o en la respuesta de tu ajax, debugea tu js para ver el formato en que regresa tu respuesta.. agrega un parseo de json al final de tu metodo _GetMenuUsuario, porque en el cliente espera un jscon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` solo funcionan cuando son compilados por el Razor que es el compilador de las vistas para asp.net. No te funcionara agregando el `string` que retornas al DOM utilizando javascript.

Cambia `Html.ActionLink` con un elemento `<a></a>` para que el DOM pueda parsearlo y mostrarlo correctamente como por ejemplo:

```
 string LineaMenu = "<li> <a href='google.com'>";
            LineaMenu += "Ir a google";
            LineaMenu += "</a></li>";
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. efectivamente tuve que cambiar la construccion dinamica en el ajax para usar <a></a> en lugar de los @Html.ActionLink.  Lo deje de la siguiente manera en los links             <li class="nav-item active">

                <a href="@Url.Action("Inicio", "Cierre", new { area = "KAM" })">Cierre Mes</a>
            </li>   ahi la construccion del enlace de forma dinamica ya sea en el ajax o a traves de una variable de modelo pasada a la vista parcial del menu funciona perfecto. Gracias por tu ayuda.